# Can all Nginx vhosts share the same ssl_session_cache?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, virtualhost

To me, [the Nginx docs about how `ssl_session_cache` works](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache), is a bit unclear. I'm wondering if this:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
```

declared either in the `http` block, or in *each* `server` (i.e. virtual host) block, results in 1) one single global cache named *SSL*, 10 MB large. Or 2) in one 10 MB cache per server, with combined size of all caches = num servers x 10 MB.

The docs:

> shared
>   a cache shared between all worker processes. The cache size is
>   specified in bytes; one megabyte can store about 4000 sessions. Each
>   shared cache should have an arbitrary name. A cache with the same name
>   can be used in several virtual servers.

If there'll be just one single cache, then I'd like to multiply its size with the number of servers. So, if I have 5 servers (i.e. 5 virtual hosts), then I'd place `ssl_session_cache` in the `http` block and:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;   # 10 * 5 = 50
```

So, the question: Does `ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;` create one 10 MB cache per server, or one 10 MB cache for all servers?

If it's per server, then is there no way to configure one single global cache, for all servers, instead? (If not possible, then why not, in case anyone knows?) Seems to me as if that would result in more efficient memory usage. (Because one server with many clients, could then use the memory that would otherwise have been dedicated to some other server that might have zero clients for the moment.)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @HassanBaig Not yet, no. Maybe if one studies the source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `ssl_session_cache` by *ngx_http_ssl_session_cache* in [nxg_http_ssl_module.c](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.c), it creates one shared memory zone named "SSL", i.e. one ssl session cache.

Any subsequent call to `ssl_session_cache` retrieves the previously configured shared memory zone named "SSL", instead of creating a new one (cmp. *ngx_shared_memory_add* in [ngx_cycle.c](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/df0dfa634d54904ea9e0714547547131a6b2da10/src/core/ngx_cycle.c)).

---

This can easily be verified by configuring different sizes for the same name like so:

```
...
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:4m;

server {
    ...
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
}
```

This results in an error message such as:

```
[emerg] the size 52428800 of shared memory zone "SSL" conflicts with already declared size  4194304 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:37
```

---

**Details**  (KajMagnus added)

The shared memory zone gets added [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/1305b8414d22610b0820f6df5841418bf98fc370/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.c#L960):

```
  sscf->shm_zone = ngx_shared_memory_add(cf, &name, n,
                                         &ngx_http_ssl_module);
```

and as you can see, different `name`s result in different caches being created. So, one can have many different shared memory caches, each one with its own unique name. However, each server, can use only one shared SSL memory zone — there's just one `shm_zone` per SSL server config, on the `ngx_http_ssl_srv_conf_t *sscf` structure.

---

**tl;dr**
Whether a SSL session cache is declared at http or server level does not matter. The same cache is used as long as the same name is assigned to the cache. To prevent an error message for caches with the same name the same size must be used throughout.

Comment: Thanks! I've been wondering for many years. I edited the answer and added a little bit details.